# Uniform Convergence (Can someone verify my work?)

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, solution-verification

Can someone verify my work here?

So I'm given the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}sin(n \pi x)}{n \pi}$ and I need to determine whether it is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

i) 2 and $\pi$ are constant so I proceed with the following:

$0\le(-1)^{n+1}sin(n\pi x)\le 1  $

$\frac{0}{n}\le\frac{(-1)^{n+1}sin(n\pi x)}{n}\le \frac{1}{n}  $

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{0}{n}\le\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}sin(n\pi x)}{n}\le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}  $

$0\le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)\le 0 $

$\therefore \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 0$

ii) Now , let $\epsilon >0$, then
$\big|f_n(x)-0\big|=\big|\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}sin(n \pi x)}{n \pi}\big| \le \frac{2\cdot 1}{\frac{n}{2}}=\frac{4}{n}<\epsilon$.

Thus, $\forall \;\epsilon>0,\;\exists $ a corresponding number $N=\frac{4}{\epsilon}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n>N$.

Hence $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Your problem is in $N=\frac{4}{\epsilon}$, with this form,doesn't necessarily a natural number. But,instead using this,you can use archimedean property, that means for every  $\epsilon>0$, there exists  $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{4}{n}<\epsilon$. This is guaranteed by archimedean property, since $\epsilon>0$ which means $\frac {4}{\epsilon}\in\mathbb {R}$, so there is $n\in\mathbb {N} $ such that $\frac {4}{\epsilon}<n $.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Is my logic okay then?

Comment: Yes, i don't see any problem there

Comment: For larger $n$, the first statement is incorrect.  The lower limit is $-1$, not $0$.   The approach still works.

Comment: I that makes sense, although I thought we "squeezed" $f_n(x)$ between the $[0,1]$ since that's the interval we're trying to show that the seq. of funs. converges uniformly?

Comment: Squeeze it between $-1\leq  (-1)^{n+1}sin (n\pi x)\leq 1$ and it works like before

Comment: Do we need abs. values on middle term if we do this?

Comment: No, all you need is edit your sentence, instead of $0\leq (-1)^{n+1}sin(n\pi x)\leq 1$ to be $0\leq | (-1)^{n+1}sin(n\pi x)|\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Your "$0 \leq (-1)^{n+1} \sin(n \pi x) \leq 1$" line is wrong. For example $n=3$ and $x=1/2$. In general for $n=4k - 1$, $k=1,2, \dots$ and $x=1/2$. So you need to use absolute value instead.

$\displaystyle \left| f_n(x) \right| = \left| \frac{2 (-1)^{n+1} \sin (n \pi x)}{n \pi} \right| \leq \frac{2}{n \pi} \left| (-1)^{n+1} \sin (n \pi x) \right| \leq \frac{2}{n \pi} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

So given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N>\dfrac{2}{\pi \epsilon}$ then for $n>N$ you have $\displaystyle \left| f_n(x) - 0 \right| \leq \frac{2}{n \pi} < \frac{2}{N \pi} < \epsilon$

for all $x \in [0,1]$. Hence $f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. (In fact on $\mathbb{R}$.)